# OData Case-insensitive Sorting

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api, odata

Do OData query supports case-insensitive query similar to SQL?

For example in SQL,

```
    //valid
    Select * From Product OrderBy lastupdateddate
    Select * From Product OrderBy LastUpdatedDate
```

While in OData,

```
    //only one of them is valid.
    /products?$orderby=lastupdateddate
    /products?$orderby=LastUpdatedDate
```

> Invalid endpoint returns error message: 
>  *"The query specified in
>   the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named
>   'lastupdateddate'.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At WebAPI HttpConfiguration:

```
//add this
config.EnableCaseInsensitive(true);
```